# Test enzyme shallow : Element is not defined

Tags: javascript, enzyme

I using enzyme to test and I have error :

ReferenceError: Items is not defined

```
function listItems() {
return (
    <Items>
        <div key="1">
            <itemContent href={'https://reactjs.org/'}>
                <Banner src={'https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BE6HQe1NzmM/V2rk2jjMk8I/AAAAAAAAYAs/7yUcpn2MzPIWPTxqZ6eZ3S84OHd5opEOwCK4B/s400/React%2B1.0.png'} height="115px" />
            </itemContent>
        </div>
        <div key="2">
            <itemContent href={'https://reactjs.org/'}>
                <Banner src={'https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BE6HQe1NzmM/V2rk2jjMk8I/AAAAAAAAYAs/7yUcpn2MzPIWPTxqZ6eZ3S84OHd5opEOwCK4B/s400/React%2B1.0.png'} height="115px" />
            </itemContent>
        </div>
        <div key="3">
            <itemContent href={'https://reactjs.org/'}>
                <Banner src={'https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BE6HQe1NzmM/V2rk2jjMk8I/AAAAAAAAYAs/7yUcpn2MzPIWPTxqZ6eZ3S84OHd5opEOwCK4B/s400/React%2B1.0.png'} height="115px" />
            </itemContent>
        </div>
    </Items>
);}
```

and then I use :

```
const wrapperList = shallow(<listItems />);
```

Can any one please tell me what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Items` is being used as a Component in the code sample.  Where is it coming from in your code?  Did you forget to `import` it?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! To more clearly, I added a new my question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113292/test-enzyme-error-referenceerror-is-not-defined
Please review and help me a little.

Comment: thanks @brain-lives-outdoors. I think I solved it.